# FTP/Host modify my code

Tags: php, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop Filezilla changing my linebreaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554960/how-can-i-stop-filezilla-changing-my-linebreaks)
>   [SFTP from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717854/sftp-from-within-php)

I have a php file which work in local, when I send it online it doesn't work so I download it back and it's now on a single line...

Basically before I send it via FileZilla FTP :

```
<?php
          code
          code
          code
?>
```

Once I download it back

```
<?phpcodecodecode?>
```

Any idea if it's FTP Client related, host related, encoding related...etc...

I've never seen that in 4 years of coding, on 10-20 different hosts.

**Edit**
I code using NotePad++, I send with FileZilla and the host is iWeb, I've formatted my computer yesterday so it may be a weird setting I have not changed or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably changing your linebreaks from Windows to UNIX style (although NotePad++ should be able to display both styles).

Try the settings from this old question: [How can I stop Filezilla changing my linebreaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554960/how-can-i-stop-filezilla-changing-my-linebreaks)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that, I tried an old trick, I opened each file, copy/paster into a new file (which was Utf-8/Unix format) and saved it under the last name and it worked...you are probably right it was the Unix format I would say.