# Why does a compiled Go program run on one Linux system but not another (same OS)?

Tags: go

I have a fairly simple Go program (just prints a message to the screen and writes to a log file, only uses built-in packages `fmt`, `log`, `os`, `path/filepath`, nothing fancy). I've written it on Windows and cross-compiled it for Linux using:

```
$env:GOOS="linux"
$env:GOARCH="amd64"
go build -o bin\progname-linux-amd64
```

The build completes successfully.

I'm trying to run the generated executable on two Linux machines, both using CentOS. It works on one, but the other fails with `21536 Illegal instruction`.

If I compile it with `$env:GOARCH="386"` then the error changes to `21534 Trace/breakpoint trap`

OS is the same on both servers: `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`

Output from `uname -a` is the same on both servers, except the hostname: `Linux server1 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 22:26:13 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Why would it work on one but not the other?

Comment: Does it run on the "troubled" machine if you compile on that machine? Also, are you using the official Go tools? And what Go version are you using?

Comment: What is the method of delivering the compiled binary to the target system, on which it fails? Is it FTP by any chance? If your systems are not somehow stripped down, please run something like `md5sum progname-linux-amd64` or `sha1sum ...` on both systems and compare the hashes.

Comment: @icza I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to build it on that machine (it's not mine), I'll report back if I do. I'm using the standard, official Go tools, running `go version` returns `go version go1.21.0 windows/amd64`

Comment: I'd first try my suggestions, as the reason might be dead-simple in fact :-)

Comment: @kostix You're right - hashes didn't match. I'm not sure of the details, but something about the file transfer process corrupted it. If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Well, with 99.9% confidence, FTP was used for transfer, and the problem is, that protocol (and many clients, including stock no-frills `ftp` clients on various OSes) defaults to a transfer mode known as "ascii" or "text" which makes the client assume the files it receives are textual and convert their EOL-terminating sequences between those of the "sending" os to that of "local". In your case, quite possible the transfer replaced all CRLFs with LFs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6156167/720999) for more.

Comment: Note that FTP is actually safe to transfer if you learn to always switch it to `binary` mode before sending binary files (actually, I'd say, any transfer session should start with this, leaving "ascii" mode to really special cases, if any).