# Sublime Text 2: How to delete blank/empty lines

Tags: sublimetext2

Let's say I had a text file with the following nine lines:

```
foo

bar

baz

qux

quux
```

How can I use Sublime Text 2 to remove all four of the blank/empty lines, leaving only five lines?

Answer (score 744, accepted):

Select the text

Press:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> on PC, or
- <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Mac or
- Click Find->Replace.

Make sure you have selected 'regular expression' by pressing:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on PC or
- <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on Mac or
- Click <kbd>.*</kbd> in the Find box.

Find what: `^\n` or `^(\r|\n\r?)`

Replace With: (nothing, leave in blank).

Comment: That works, thank you! Is there a way to bind that find/replace to a keyboard shortcut or somehow save it for quick access? I googled it and couldn't find anything

Comment: Small suggestion use `^(\r|\n\r?)` to cover all possible line breaks.

Comment: For me (Sublime Text 2) shortcut is (Alt + Cmd + F) then as describe by Hugp Corra

Comment: On OS X, regex is enabled with Command-Alt-R (while the Find window is open)

Comment: A better way to find all empty lines (including ones with whitespace) would be:

    `^[\s]*?[\n\r]+`

Comment: @Crates you don't need the `?`, as a `*` also matches zero occurences and `\s*` will match the extra '\r' when for example editing windows text in a linux environment, so `^\s*$` does the trick.

Comment: And small last step: press Ctrl + Alt + Enter to replace them all

Comment: Also you can do it on multiple files and folder also. visit this link http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html

Comment: This continues to work properly in Sublime Text 3. :-)

Answer (score 72):

The regexp in Hugo's answer is correct when there is no spaces in the line. In case if there are space regexp can be `^\s+$`

Comment: That assumes that there IS whitespace. Also, it won't work for actually substituting the lines with nothing. Try `^[\s]*?[\n\r]+` instead. I've tested that, and it works.

Comment: Crates's solution should be the best answer. However, `^[\s]*[\n\r]+` should be enough.

Answer (score 25):

There are also some ST2/ST3 Plugins for such tasks. I do like these two:

- [Delete Blank Lines](https://github.com/NicholasBuse/sublime_DeleteBlankLines)  (also available via Package Control)
- [Trailing Spaces](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces)  (also available via Package Control)

The first one has two methods for removing empty/unnecessary lines. One of them called `Delete Surplus Blank Lines` which is cool. It removes only those lines that are followed by another empty line

Answer (score 12):

Don't even know how this whole thing works, but I tried 
`^\s*$` and didn't work (leaving still some empty lines).

**This instead `^\s*` works for me** 


{sublime text 3}

Answer (score 10):

A Find/Replace solution:

Regex Find:`\s+`

Replace with:  //single space

Comment: Actually, this : $\s+

Answer (score 10):

## Sublime Text 2 & 3

The Comments of @crates work for me,

Step 1: Simply press on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Step 2: press on RegEX key

Step 3: write this in the Find: `^[\s]*?[\n\r]+`

Step 4: replace all

Answer (score 9):

Their is a more easily way to do that without regex.
you have just to select the whole text.
then go to: Edit--> Permute Lines --> Unique.

That's all. and all blank lines will be deleted.

Comment: This will delete ALL non-unique lines. Not just blanks. So, say you have HTML with a lot of lines being a single closing </div>, it will delete them all except the first. Or in code, it will delete all your closing }. This is not reliable to delete just blank lines, understand what it does.

Comment: This may not exact match the origin question, but this is the only native and easiest solution when a) You're sure there are no other duplicated lines. b) You're not fan of regexp.

Comment: Also this leaves one empty line always, as it is always unique within dataset

Answer (score 7):

I had to use:

replace \n^\s*\n
with    \n

The https://github.com/NicholasBuse/sublime_DeleteBlankLines plugin did nothing at all.

Comment: Make sure you select the area you want it to effect and then use the respective shortcut keys

**Windows**: _Ctrl+Alt+Backspace_ (Delete Blank Lines)
_Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Backspace_ (Delete Surplus Blank Lines)

**OSX**: _Ctrl+Alt+Delete_ (Delete Blank Lines)
_Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Delete_ (Delete Blank Lines)

**Linux**: _Ctrl+Alt+Backspace_ (Delete Blank Lines)
_Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Backspace_ (Delete Surplus Blank Lines)

Answer (score 6):

Simpler than I thought. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> Followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> Then Select Regular Expression `.*` . Replace `\n\n` with `\n`. Voila!

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for this:

```
^\n|^\s+$
```

it will not delete the line, if there is content with white space or tabs in front>

e.g.:

these will not be deleted:
...space... abc

...tab... abc

this will:

...space...  ...nothing else...

...tab... ...nothing else...

Answer (score 3):

Using multiple selections: select one pair of line breaks, then use Quick Find All (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), or Quick Add Next (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) repeatedly, to select them all; then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to replace them with single line breaks.

Comment: In large documents, I find this crashes Sublime.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wonderful package (for Sublime 2 & 3) called '**Trimmer**' which deletes empty lines. It also does many other useful things.

Refer this: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Trimmer

Comment: is there any analog for sublime 4?

Answer (score 2):

Another way, you can use the command line `cc.dbl` of ConyEdit (a plugin) to delete blank lines or empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

There's also "Join lines". If on OSX, select all your text, and press CMD-J a few times, and it will collapse your selection by line, removing the line breaks.

Edit: This approach will leave you with everything on one line, which is not what you asked for.

Comment: i see where you're going with this though.. this suggestion results in dragging all content into one line, but a macro would make this work: (OSX keys) `ctrl-q` (record macro), `cmd-j` (join lines), `down arrow`, `ctrl-q` (end macro). Then `shift-ctrl-q` to repeat as often as required...

Answer (score 1):

For those who are curious of sublime text editor, the [unofficial-documentation](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#regular-expressions) may be interesting!

Answer (score 1):

To find extra spaces and blank lines press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
Select **Regular Expressions** Find

`[\n\r]{2,}`

and then replace with

`\n`

to remove all kind of spaces in sublime and dreamviewr

Answer (score 0):

Using find / replace, try pasting a selection starting at the end of the line above the blank line and ends at the beginning of the line after the blank.  This works for a single blank line.  You can repeat the process for multiple blank lines as well.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, put your selection in the find box and put a single newline in the replace box via copy/paste or other method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case some empty lines contained the unicode character **zero width space** (U+200b). To rid empty lines, including the ones with this unicode character:

```
\s\x{200b}|^\s
```

Answer (score -1):

If   `^\n` does not work properly   ===>   try   `.*[^\w]\n`