# How can I select (or simply delete) every other line in Sublime Text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

If I edit a WordPress template in Sublime Text 2 after it has been edited in the WordPress editor, every other line is blank. I'd like to remove those ... <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>del</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>del</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>del</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>del</kbd> is getting really annoying.

*Note this is different from deleting all blank lines (i.e., [Sublime Text 2: How to delete blank/empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008986/sublime-text-2-how-to-delete-blank-empty-lines)). Some lines are intentionally blank.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find what: `\n\n`

Replace with: `\n`

If the blank lines are odd, put the cursor on line 2. Otherwise, put the cursor on line 1.

Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>