# Endlines In Edited PHP File Disappear

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8, ftp, formatting

I have a unique problem where no endline's are saved to my javascript and php files after editing them.

I have downloaded my websites javascript and php files using ftp so I can edit them. I have edited them in Notepad++ then reuploaded them. And everything broke because all the new code I added have no endlines in them, just one long line, so some lines have a comment in them and it is causing syntax errors.

What could cause such a weird problem?

Important Informatiom:

- The existing code in the edited files have correct endlines/formatting. Its just the new code/text that is added.
- Each of the files are UTF8 encoded without a BOM. I didn't set this encoding, thats how they came from filezilla.
- I am on Windows 8.1
- Inside Notepad++ the file looks fine, with endlines and correct formatting. When I view the files in Chrome's source browser (for eg; the javascript file) it shows that all the new code is on one line without any newlines (the original code has all its newlines weirdly).
- If i search the editted files for the character /n in Notepad++ it only finds endline chars on the existing code lines but not on my new code, even though that new code is shown on different lines. Such a weird problem.

Comment: If you re-download the files after editing them are the newlines gone?  Is it possible that your webserver is processing the files through some sort of minimizer module?

Comment: try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/39520/downloading-files-with-filezilla-result-in-newline-r-n-n) so tell your client to handle all files as binary so it won't mess with them

Answer (score 0):

Use this answer [How can I stop Filezilla changing my linebreaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554960/how-can-i-stop-filezilla-changing-my-linebreaks)

In FileZilla 2.2.32, go Edit > Settings > File transfer settings > ASCII/Binary. Set it to always binary: that should do the trick.

In FileZilla 3.5.0 the setting is in Edit > Settings > Transfers > File Types > Default transfer type > Binary.